# No such module 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4' Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, cocoapods

I want to create logging with facebook and use parse server.

I install all needed library but i have issues with **ParseFacebookUtilsV4**

I received error message:

> No such module 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4'

But this module are installed.

[image]

Error:

[image]

Comment: Make sure you opened the project using workspace and try to product->clean and then run the project. The error should be gone by now.

Comment: If the pod hasn't shown up after installing, (Make sure you pod was installed) restart xcode and check that it shows up in the file directory.

Comment: Stil some error, now i get "No known class method for selector 'taskWithException:'"

Comment: Maybe then you need to update your Cocoapods Repository by `pod update` or `pod repo update` since it might be an outdated version of the Framework

Answer (score -1):

try to clean project and check By clicking cmd + shift + K